# Breadcrumbs category name is missing on product detail page

Tags: magento, magento2, breadcrumbs

Im working on Magento 2.1.1 . When I open product page from product list page i cant able to see category name on breadcrumbs . It just shows homepage url followed by product name . Very rarely I can able to see full breadcrumbs with category name .

[breadcrumbs - category name is missing .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuQgz.png)

Could someone please give me some ideas to solve this issue?

Comment: Hi, This is normal behavior. In Magento2 as well as 1. Let's say your product named P is in the category B who has a parent category named A. 
He opens the search page => No Breadcrumb. He opens the A category and from there the product P => Breadcrumb will be A/P. He opens category B, then the product => Breadcrumb will be A/B/P. So same product but not same breadcrumb. This allows magento to handle the breadcrumb properly for products that are in multiple categories.

Comment: Hi , I agree with you . But for me category breadcrumbs not working like above . When  opens category B, then the product => Breadcrumb will be A/B/P , but in my case  breadcrumbs just like this Home/P , categories are missing

Comment: Hi , Is there any updates regarding this issue ?

Comment: Hi , Kindly let me know if any updates regarding this issue .

Comment: Hi , Anyone have any idea regarding this issue .

Comment: Hi , I have checked this issue on Latest version 2.1.4 , There also i faced the same breadcrumbs issue. I Found an option to add category with product url from back end . Once enabled it Breadcrumbs with category displayed on product detail page . But If I open the same product from any other page like home , search , its not displaying full breadcrumbs . Just showing Home-> product name . .

Comment: Hi , Any update regarding this issue .

Comment: Hi , Please let me know if you have any suggestion related to this issue.

Comment: Hi , Anyone have any solution to solve this problem .

Answer (score 2):

This issue is already reported to Magento 2 GitHub repository here:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7967

There is a gist linked in the comments which has a workaround:
https://gist.github.com/mbahar/82703c4b95d924d9bc8e6990202fdeba

Answer (score 2):

I've found solution, approved by Magento team. Because if you use approaches with block rewrites or plugins and you have some extensions that use Breadcrumbs block or Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View.php, you'll have problems.
So, you have to customize just app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/web/js/product/breadcrumbs.js.
So, here is a full code:

```
    /**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Theme/js/model/breadcrumb-list'
], function ($, breadcrumbList) {
    'use strict';

    return function (widget) {
        $.widget('mage.breadcrumbs', widget, {
            options: {
                categoryUrlSuffix: '',
                useCategoryPathInUrl: false,
                product: '',
                menuContainer: '[data-action="navigation"] > ul'
            },

            /** @inheritdoc */
            _render: function () {
                this._appendCatalogCrumbs();
                this._super();
            },

            /**
             * Append category and product crumbs.
             *
             * @private
             */
            _appendCatalogCrumbs: function () {
                var categoryCrumbs = this._resolveCategoryCrumbs();

                categoryCrumbs.forEach(function (crumbInfo) {
                    breadcrumbList.push(crumbInfo);
                });

                if (this.options.product) {
                    breadcrumbList.push(this._getProductCrumb());
                }
            },

            /**
             * Resolve categories crumbs.
             *
             * @return Array
             * @private
             */
            _resolveCategoryCrumbs: function () {
                var menuItem = this._resolveCategoryMenuItem(),
                    categoryCrumbs = [];

                if (menuItem !== null && menuItem.length) {
                    categoryCrumbs.unshift(this._getCategoryCrumb(menuItem));

                    while ((menuItem = this._getParentMenuItem(menuItem)) !== null) {
                        categoryCrumbs.unshift(this._getCategoryCrumb(menuItem));
                    }
                }

                return categoryCrumbs;
            },

            /**
             * Returns crumb data.
             *
             * @param {Object} menuItem
             * @return {Object}
             * @private
             */
            _getCategoryCrumb: function (menuItem) {

                return {
                    'name': 'category',
                    'label': menuItem.text(),
                    'link': menuItem.attr('href'),
                    'title': ''
                };
            },

            /**
             * Returns product crumb.
             *
             * @return {Object}
             * @private
             */
            _getProductCrumb: function () {
                return {
                    'name': 'product',
                    'label': this.options.product,
                    'link': '',
                    'title': ''
                };
            },

            /**
             * Find parent menu item for current.
             *
             * @param {Object} menuItem
             * @return {Object|null}
             * @private
             */
            _getParentMenuItem: function (menuItem) {
                var classes,
                    classNav,
                    parentClass,
                    parentMenuItem = null;

                if (!menuItem) {
                    return null;
                }

                classes = menuItem.parent().attr('class');
                classNav = classes.match(/(nav\-)[0-9]+(\-[0-9]+)+/gi);

                if (classNav) {
                    classNav = classNav[0];
                    parentClass = classNav.substr(0, classNav.lastIndexOf('-'));

                    if (parentClass.lastIndexOf('-') !== -1) {
                        parentMenuItem = $(this.options.menuContainer).find('.' + parentClass + ' > a');
                        parentMenuItem = parentMenuItem.length ? parentMenuItem : null;
                    }
                }

                return parentMenuItem;
            },

            /**
             * Returns category menu item.
             *
             * Tries to resolve category from url or from referrer as fallback and
             * find menu item from navigation menu by category url.
             *
             * @return {Object|null}
             * @private
             */
            _resolveCategoryMenuItem: function () {
                var categoryUrl = this._resolveCategoryUrl(),
                    menu = $(this.options.menuContainer),
                    categoryMenuItem = null;

                if (categoryUrl && menu.length) {
                    categoryMenuItem = menu.find('a[href="' + categoryUrl + '"]');
                }

                return categoryMenuItem;
            },

            /**
             * Returns category url.
             *
             * @return {String}
             * @private
             */
            _resolveCategoryUrl: function () {
                var categoryUrl;

                if (this.options.useCategoryPathInUrl) {
                    // In case category path is used in product url - resolve category url from current url.
                    categoryUrl = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
                    categoryUrl = categoryUrl.substring(0, categoryUrl.lastIndexOf('/')) +
                        this.options.categoryUrlSuffix;
                } else {
                    // In other case - try to resolve it from referrer (without parameters).
                    categoryUrl = document.referrer;

                    if (categoryUrl.indexOf('?') > 0) {
                        categoryUrl = categoryUrl.substr(0, categoryUrl.indexOf('?'));
                    }
                }

                return categoryUrl;
            }
        });

        return $.mage.breadcrumbs;
    };
});
```

And here is a link to merge request: [ENGCOM-1707](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/99d33d3e803258d63dd55a9eb2c87e21aa70d8d4)

Comment: I have used this js code, but still not getting the category name on product detail page.

Comment: @Vladishev  Is this newly added functionality ? I don't have in my 2.2.2 version. Also by looking at the `breadcrumbs.js`  in `_resolveCategoryUrl` using `document.referrer`  when category not included in the product url doesn't seem right. I've just done a test, It only works if you are coming from category page and not refresh the page otherwise is empty

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried the above workaround, but people say it's not always working.

Meanwhile the following seems to be working nicely (I've just tested it):
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7967#issuecomment-315310890

1. [Vendor]/[Module]/etc/frontend/events.xml

   ```
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
       <event name="catalog_controller_product_init_after">
   <observer instance="[Vendor]\[Module]\Observer\Catalog\Product\FullPathBreadcrumbs" name="addProductFullPathBreadcrumbs"/>
   </event>
   </config>
   ```
2. [Vendor]/[Module]//Observer/Catalog/Product/FullPathBreadcrumbs

   ```
   <?php
   namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Observer\Catalog\Product;

   class FullPathBreadcrumbs implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
   {

   protected $_registry;

   protected $_categoryRepository;

   public function __construct(
       \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
       \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository
   ) {
       $this->_registry=$registry;
       $this->_categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
   }


   /**
    * Execute observer
    *
    * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    * @return void
    */
   public function execute(
       \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
   ) {
       $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
       if ($product != null && !$this->_registry->registry('current_category')) {
           $cats = $product->getAvailableInCategories();

           if(sizeof($cats)===1){
               $last = $cats[0];
           }else{
               end($cats);
               $last = prev($cats);
           }


           if($last) {
               $category = $this->_categoryRepository->get($last);
               $this->_registry->register('current_category', $category, true);
           }
       }
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: Check the latest version there was a release which has this create breadcrumbs based on last category/location you were in. It's a bit strange if you have multiple tabs/windows open as a category which does not live in a category can show breadcrumb if you navigate to a category in another tab/window using the same session space.

Comment: Thanks your answer is very helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution for the above issue. Kindly check the below js file.
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/web/js/product/breadcrumbs.js
The breadcrumbs.js file has taken some classes by using the menu. If you are customizing the menu, the category name is missed in the breadcrumbs-Product detail page.
Menu must have the following class:
1)Menu nav section must have "data-action="navigation".
2)Menu li element must have "category-item" class.
3)The parent li element must have "nav-1","nav-2",.. class and the sub child li("nav-1")element must have "nav-1-1","nav-1-2" and so on..

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Theme/js/model/breadcrumb-list'
], function ($, breadcrumbList) {
    'use strict';

    return function (widget) {
        // calling menu class and data-action "categoryItemSelector","menuContainer"**
        $.widget('mage.breadcrumbs', widget, {
            options: {
                categoryUrlSuffix: '',
                useCategoryPathInUrl: false,
                product: '',
                categoryItemSelector: '.category-item',
                menuContainer: '[data-action="navigation"] > ul'**
            },

            /** @inheritdoc */
            _render: function () {
                this._appendCatalogCrumbs();
                this._super();
            },

            /**
             * Append category and product crumbs.
             *
             * @private
             */
            _appendCatalogCrumbs: function () {
                var categoryCrumbs = this._resolveCategoryCrumbs();

                categoryCrumbs.forEach(function (crumbInfo) {
                    breadcrumbList.push(crumbInfo);
                });

                if (this.options.product) {
                    breadcrumbList.push(this._getProductCrumb());
                }
            },

            /**
             * Resolve categories crumbs.
             *
             * @return Array
             * @private
             */
            _resolveCategoryCrumbs: function () {
                var menuItem = this._resolveCategoryMenuItem(),
                    categoryCrumbs = [];

                if (menuItem !== null && menuItem.length) {
                    categoryCrumbs.unshift(this._getCategoryCrumb(menuItem));

                    while ((menuItem = this._getParentMenuItem(menuItem)) !== null) {
                        categoryCrumbs.unshift(this._getCategoryCrumb(menuItem));
                    }
                }

                return categoryCrumbs;
            },

            /**
             * Returns crumb data.
             *
             * @param {Object} menuItem
             * @return {Object}
             * @private
             */
            _getCategoryCrumb: function (menuItem) {
                return {
                    'name': 'category',
                    'label': menuItem.text(),
                    'link': menuItem.attr('href'),
                    'title': ''
                };
            },

            /**
             * Returns product crumb.
             *
             * @return {Object}
             * @private
             */
            _getProductCrumb: function () {
                return {
                    'name': 'product',
                    'label': this.options.product,
                    'link': '',
                    'title': ''
                };
            },

            /**
             * Find parent menu item for current.
             *
             * @param {Object} menuItem
             * @return {Object|null}
             * @private
             */
            _getParentMenuItem: function (menuItem) {
                var classes,
                    classNav,
                    parentClass,
                    parentMenuItem = null;

                if (!menuItem) {
                    return null;
                }

                classes = menuItem.parent().attr('class');
                // calling menu nav class**********
                **classNav = classes.match(/(nav\-)[0-9]+(\-[0-9]+)+/gi);**

                if (classNav) {
                    classNav = classNav[0];
                    parentClass = classNav.substr(0, classNav.lastIndexOf('-'));

                    if (parentClass.lastIndexOf('-') !== -1) {
                        parentMenuItem = $(this.options.menuContainer).find('.' + parentClass + ' > a');
                        parentMenuItem = parentMenuItem.length ? parentMenuItem : null;
                    }
                }

                return parentMenuItem;
            },

            /**
             * Returns category menu item.
             *
             * Tries to resolve category from url or from referrer as fallback and
             * find menu item from navigation menu by category url.
             *
             * @return {Object|null}
             * @private
             */
            _resolveCategoryMenuItem: function () {
                var categoryUrl = this._resolveCategoryUrl(),
                    menu = $(this.options.menuContainer),
                    categoryMenuItem = null;

                if (categoryUrl && menu.length) {
                    categoryMenuItem = menu.find(
                        this.options.categoryItemSelector +
                        ' > a[href="' + categoryUrl + '"]'
                    );
                }

                return categoryMenuItem;
            },

            /**
             * Returns category url.
             *
             * @return {String}
             * @private
             */
            _resolveCategoryUrl: function () {
                var categoryUrl;

                if (this.options.useCategoryPathInUrl) {
                    // In case category path is used in product url - resolve category url from current url.
                    categoryUrl = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
                    categoryUrl = categoryUrl.substring(0, categoryUrl.lastIndexOf('/')) +
                        this.options.categoryUrlSuffix;
                } else {
                    // In other case - try to resolve it from referrer (without parameters).
                    categoryUrl = document.referrer;

                    if (categoryUrl.indexOf('?') > 0) {
                        categoryUrl = categoryUrl.substr(0, categoryUrl.indexOf('?'));
                    }
                }

                return categoryUrl;
            }
        });

        return $.mage.breadcrumbs;
    };
});
```